# Mifare 1K writing data in two blocks

Tags: c++, nfc, rfid, apdu

I'm working with APDU command for writing and reading an RFID card. I can read from block number 2 and write 16 bytes of data, but I have a problem writing longer data. How can I manage to do that? I have tried to write in two blocks but it doesn't work.

this the way I implemented my code in the operation of writing:

```
// write...
//


if (nres == SM_SUCCESS)// &&
//bAPDURes )
{
nlenrcv = sizeof(btRcv);
nlencmd = 0;

btCmd[nlencmd++] = 0xFF; // CLA
btCmd[nlencmd++] = 0xD6; // INS
btCmd[nlencmd++] = 0x00; // P1, Mifare Block Number MSB, for mifare it is always 0x00
btCmd[nlencmd++] = 0x04; // P2, Mifare Block Number LSB
btCmd[nlencmd++] = 32; // Lc, Data Length
memcpy(btCmd + nlencmd, btWrite, 32);
nlencmd += 32;
nres = m_Smart.RFTransmit(DEV_INTERNALRF, nlencmd, btCmd, (DWORD*)&nlenrcv, btRcv);
```

Comment: Well, this question is something we can't answer exactly -- I don't think its possible to post a minimal reproducible example. And the message looks well formed to me.... Here's some questions that might help you find an answer: 1. Are you sure P1 and P2 are big endian (have you tried swapping them?) 2. Are you sure the CLA  + INS combination can write more than 2 bytes? 3. Are you sure that this `RFTransmit` library function is sending the right thing to the card? 4. How do you know "it doesn't work"? - could there be a problem with the way the program verifies this data write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send each block separately. The Mifare Classic `Write` command will only write one block at once.

See Section 12.3 of the [Card's Data sheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF1S70YYX_V1.pdf)

So RFTransmit the write command for the first 16 bytes to the first block and RFTransmit the write command for the second 16 bytes to the next block.

Comment: I have been trying to writing some data to my mifare classic cards. first I send these two commands which returns 90 00:

Load Mifare Keys: FF 82 20 01 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF

Authenticate: FF 86 00 03 05 01 00 05 60 00

now I'm write commands to sector 0 and block 3 and block 4 by this commands APDU_WRITE_data_1 : FF D 00 03 16 APDU_WRITE_data_1 : FF D 00 04 16  But it doesn't work is it the APDU for writing wrong?

Comment: It is difficult to say what the problem is as you seem to be using pseudo APDU's and thus you are dealing with the card reading hardware and how it converts these in to real commands the Card understands and you don't specify the exact make and model of the card reader. I would open a new question with details about your new problem.

Comment: thank you for your response actually i have tested to write data in block 2 it correctly but as i mentioned before that i have data longer then 16 bits so i'm trying to spreate data in block 3 and 4 . i opened a new question about this new problem